# Inverse of $f(x) = 18sin(\frac{x\pi}{7})+20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

This is an exercise taken from [Mooculus](https://mooculus.osu.edu/)-textbook (page 17, exercise 5 to be exact).

The task given is to find an inverse for $f(x) = 18\sin(\frac{x\pi}{7})+20$ (restricting domain to $[3.5,10.5]$) and interpret $f^{-1}(20)$. I'm given that $f^{-1}(20) = 7$ but what I've come up with as an inverse does not yield anything like that.

Here is how I've tried to approach this (only tool I'm aware of for finding inverses is to swap y and x, then solve for y).

$f(x) = 18\sin(\frac{x\pi}{7})+20 \Longrightarrow y = 18\sin(\frac{x\pi}{7})+20$

$x = 18\sin(\frac{y\pi}{7})+20 \Longrightarrow x-20=18\sin(\frac{y\pi}{7}) \Longrightarrow$
$\frac{x-20}{18}= \sin(\frac{y\pi}{7}) \Longrightarrow \arcsin({\frac{x-20}{18}})=\frac{x\pi}{7} \Longrightarrow$
$7\arcsin(\frac{x-20}{18}) = y\pi \Longrightarrow \frac{7\arcsin(\frac{x-20}{18})}{\pi} = y$.

But $\frac{7\arcsin(\frac{20-20}{18})}{\pi} = 0$, not 7.

The original problem in the book is:

[image]

Comment: As arcsin is a multi-valued function the inverse will depend on how you restrict the domain. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18*sin%28pi*x%2F7%29%2B20 for multiple y values = 20 (particularly at x = 0 and x = 7).

Comment: In the exercise domain is restricted to [3.5, 10.5] which means it's possible to find an inverse, but that doesn't help me much as my feeble try isn't giving 7 with 20 as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In much the same way that $\sin(x)=0$ has multiple values for $x$,  $\arcsin(0)=x$ also has multiple values for $x$. In order to make $\arcsin(x)$ a function, we assign a specific domain. The principal domain is $-\frac\pi2\le y\le\frac\pi2$.
However, this question has a different domain so $\arcsin(0)$ can take different values. I will list a few possibilities(that are positive) irrespective of the domain given.
$$\arcsin(0)=0,\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi,4\pi, 5\pi...n\pi \, \text{for}\ \ n  \in \mathbb{Z}$$

This can easily be seen by drawing the unit circle.

The domain $X=[3.5, 10.5]$ refers to the value of $t$ and in your case $y$. So, looking at the possibilities the only appropriate answer is $\pi$.

$$\frac{7\arcsin(0)}{\pi}=\frac{7\times0}{\pi} = 0<3.5 \implies \notin X $$
$$\frac{7\arcsin(0)}{\pi}=\frac{7\times \pi}{\pi} = 3.5<7<10.5 \implies \in X $$
$$\frac{7\arcsin(0)}{\pi}=\frac{7\times 2\pi}{\pi} = 14>10.5 \implies \notin X $$

$h^{-1}(20)$ can be interpreted as the time needed to reach a height of $20$ m.

Comment: So the inverse I've found is correct?

Comment: @2305843008139952128 Your inverse function is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that $\arcsin $ is a multi valued function?

If the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) is $\displaystyle y,-\frac\pi2\le y\le\frac\pi2$ the [general value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#General_solutions) is $n\pi+(-1)^ny$ where $n$ is an integer

Here $y=0\implies $ the general value is $n\pi$